# How do I properly use COUNT on 3 tables joined together?

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have 3 tables I want to join.
**students**, **tardiness** and **absenteeism**.

**students** contains the required information for every students.

**tardiness** and **absenteeism**.Their structure are pretty much the same. Both contains identical columns like student_id, date, etc...

**My goal is to count the the number of absenteeism and tardiness and put it in the same row as the student with equal student_id.**

Ex.
**students** table:

```
student_id  name
a1          Josh
a2          Pete
a3          Gabe
a4          Howard
```

**tardiness** table:

```
student_id  date
a2          January 1,2016
a4          January 23,2016
```

**absenteeism** table:

```
student_id  date
a1          Feb. 2,2009
a2          August 3,2011
a2          August 4,2011
a4          March 18,2016
a4          June 28,2016
a4          June 29,2016
a4          July 15,2016
a4          July 16,2016
a4          July 29,2016
```

I already tried some. But this is the closest one I've came up so far.

```
SELECT students.student_id,
    COUNT(absenteeism.student_id) AS absents, 
    COUNT(tardiness.student_id) AS tardi
FROM students
    LEFT JOIN absenteeism ON students.student_id = absenteeism.student_id
    LEFT JOIN tardiness ON students.student_id = tardiness.student_id
GROUP BY students.student_id
```

And the result was

```
student_id  absents  tardi
a1          1        0
a2          2        2
a3          0        0
a4          6        6
```

I only got the number of absents right. The problem is a2 and a4 always have the same number of absents and tardiness.

**The correct result should be like this...**

```
student_id  absents  tardi
    a1          1        0
    a2          2        1
    a3          0        0
    a4          6        1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out with the help of this topic [MYSQL Left Join COUNTS from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349189/mysql-left-join-counts-from-multiple-tables)

**I added distinct on count and use each table's primary key instead of student_id.**

```
SELECT students.student_id,
 COUNT(distinct absenteeism.absent_id) AS absents, 
 COUNT(distinct tardiness.tardi_id) AS tardi
FROM students
 LEFT JOIN absenteeism ON absenteeism.student_id = students.student_id
 LEFT JOIN tardiness ON tardiness.student_id = students.student_id
GROUP BY students.student_id
```

My mistake was using same column **student_id** in absenteeism and tardiness. That is why using

```
COUNT(distinct absenteeism.student_id)
COUNT(distinct tardiness.student_id)
```

would only result to

```
student_id  absents  tardi
a1          1        0
a2          1        1
a3          0        0
a4          1        1
```