# MySQL - getting row counts when multiple tables are left joined

Tags: mysql

I have following three tables

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `aid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ts` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Each user is represented by account (aid) and each user owns couple of categories. Also, each user has products arranged by categories and sales timestamp.

I am trying to list all users with number of categories, total number of products and max ts. It is possible that a user has no categories or no products or both and in that case, it needs to show zero(0) count. Hence, **I can't use inner join**.

```
select count(c.cid) cc, count(p.pid) cp from accounts a 
           left join categories c on c.aid=a.aid 
           left join products p on p.cid=c.cid group by a.aid;
```

However, this does not show counts correctly because of two left join and hence rows are more. So if number of products are 5 and categories is 1, it shows count 5 for both. And so on.

Can someone help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL Left Join COUNTS from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349189/mysql-left-join-counts-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: it does, thank you